# BeautifulSoup Tag Removal

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have am looking to parse a HTML table with Python/BeautifulSoup...

This is my first attempt at coding anything in Python, so its probably not the most efficient.

I grabbed a function another post here (works great for the most part), but I am running into a couple of problems.

The code I am running is here:

```
def strip_tags(html, invalid_tags):
    bs2 = BeautifulSoup(str(html))
    for tag in bs2.findAll(True):
        if tag.name in invalid_tags:
            s = ""      

            for c in tag.contents:
                if not isinstance(c, NavigableString):
                    c = strip_tags(unicode(c), invalid_tags)
                s += unicode(c)

            tag.replaceWith(s)
    return bs2

invalid_tags = ['td','b']

for row in bs.findAll('tr'):
    col = row.findAll('td')

for index,item in enumerate(col):
    t = item.findAll('a')
    for ta in t:
        ta.replaceWithChildren()
        col[index] == item  

for item in col:
    print(strip_tags(item.string,invalid_tags).string
```

The raw data table (HTML) looks like this:

```
<td align="left">11/10</td>
<td>N ARMY</td>
<td>-7.5</td>
<td>NL</td>
<td><b>76-65</b></td>
<td><span style="color:green">W</span></td>
<td><span style="color:green">W</span></td>
<td></td>
<td class="cell4">50.0%</td>
<td class="cell4">76.9%</td>
<td class="cell4">37.5%</td>
<td class="cell5">37.1%</td>
<td class="cell5">90.0%</td>
<td class="cell5">29.4%</td>
```

When I run the strip_tags function, It works for all the tags except for the second line... 'None' is returned as the output.

If anyone could provide any insight on why this is happening I would greatly appreciate it.

edit: wow thanks for everyone's quick responses. anyhow, here is what happens when I run the code:

```
11/10
None
-7.5
NL
76-65
W
W
None
50.0%
76.9%
37.5%
37.1%
90.0%
29.4%
```

The problem lies around the second line, where it returns 'None' instead of 'N ARMY'. So yes, ideally I would like just the text that is found within the tags.

Comment: What output were you looking for instead? BeautifulSoup also has the `.stripped_strings` iterable, which makes most of this unnecessary if all you want is the text from the table.

Comment: Your indentation looks off; the `for index, item in enumerate(col):`  and `for item in col:` blocks should *probably* be indented to be part of the preceding `for` loop.

Comment: You provided the input html, but I am confused what output you want from it. Can you post what it *should* return?

Comment: thanks everyone, i updated the first post with the desired output.

Comment: Is the supplied HTML above the entirety of the HTML file that you are trying to parse?

Comment: Why are you manually removing the tags? Any `tag` element in `BeautifulSoup` has a `get_text()` method which return the the info sans html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the output you want correctly, you shouldn't need to do any manual removing of tags -- that's why we use `BeautifulSoup`! ;)

What you need to call is the `get_text()` method on the `tag` instances that `find_all()` returns.

Using your sample html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">11/10</td>
        <td>N ARMY</td>
        <td>-7.5</td>
        <td>NL</td>
        <td><b>76-65</b></td>
        <td><span style="color:green">W</span></td>
        <td><span style="color:green">W</span></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="cell4">50.0%</td>
        <td class="cell4">76.9%</td>
        <td class="cell4">37.5%</td>
        <td class="cell5">37.1%</td>
        <td class="cell5">90.0%</td>
        <td class="cell5">29.4%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

A simple iteration over the `td`s, and a call to `get_text()` and we're good to go!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('test.html', 'rb') as html: #My local version of your html file
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read())

for td in soup.find_all('td'):
    print td.get_text()
```

This gives the output:

```
11/10
N ARMY
-7.5
NL
76-65
W
W

50.0%
76.9%
37.5%
37.1%
90.0%
29.4%
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Comment: I was looking for exactly this. Everyone was talking about `decompose` and `extract` methods, but none worked. Thanks for the tip!